# Can't switch workspace with "win key+scrolling mouse up and down" using ubuntu on xorg

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, xorg, workspaces, wayland

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I switched from wayland to xorg because I noticed that the display on ubuntu on xorg is better when I use fractional scaling. But now I noticed that I can't switch workspace using the combination "win+scrolling mouse up or down" to switch workspace to the right or left.
I can do it only with "ctrl+alt+arrow" or with "win" and after one second I can switch with the scrolling mouse. I don't want this, I want to switch workspace quiclky with "win+scrolling mouse up or down" like on wayland. Someone help me?
Sorry for my english, I don't know well writing english.